# How to specify bar colors in a jqPlot stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

How do I specify my own colors for the bars in a jqPlot stacked bar chart? I am talking about setting different colors for single bars. I have gone through a couple of examples, but all of them use the default colors. Is there a way to explicitly set the colors for the bars in a stacked bar chart?

[image]

Here is the code I have now:

```
var s1=[11,28,22,47,11,11]; 
var s2=[0,6,3,0,0,0];
var s3=[1,0,3,0,0,0 ];
var dataArray = [s1, s2, s3];

var ticks =  bcdarr;

var options = {
    title: ' STATUS',
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true
        },
        rendererOptions: { 
            barWidth: 25,
            varyBarColor: true,
            },
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks,
        },
        yaxis: {
            //autoscale: true,
            //label: 'Application Count',
            min : 0,
            tickInterval : 5,
            max:50
        }
    },
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: -30,
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you checked http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php. Also would be helpful if you can paste what have you tried yet.

Comment: Almas...Thanks for you quick response!! Yes, I have been to the same link before coming here. I edited my question to have an stacked bar chart I am referring to. How do I specify my own colors there ? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to look for documentation on how to do things is the [API Documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html). It has documentation on each component and plugin and the options available for each.

As [almas shaikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315228/almas-shaikh) implied, the setting which changes the colors of the sections of the bars in a stacked barchart is the `seriesColors` attribute.  This is an array with the colors defined as text strings as you would provide for CSS, or a `style`.

In the example from which you took the above image to get ([**working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nn7t8pjb/2/)):
[image: Same plot with different colors]

You can add:

```
//Define colors for the stacked bars:
seriesColors: ["#FDF396", "#ABFD96", "#96A0FD"],
```

The complete function call would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
  var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 4];
  var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
  plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {
    //Define colors for the stacked bars:
    seriesColors: ["#FDF396", "#ABFD96", "#96A0FD"],

    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
    stackSeries: true,
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
          // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
          barMargin: 30,
          // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
          // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
          highlightMouseDown: true    
      },
      pointLabels: {show: true}
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
          renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
      },
      yaxis: {
        // Don't pad out the bottom of the data range.  By default,
        // axes scaled as if data extended 10% above and below the
        // actual range to prevent data points right on grid boundaries.
        // Don't want to do that here.
        padMin: 0
      }
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      location: 'e',
      placement: 'outside'
    }      
  });
  // Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
  // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
  // clicked along with the data for that point.
  $('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
      $('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
    }
  ); 
});
```

**Additional (point labels):**
The best place to look for documentation on how to do things is the [API Documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html). It has documentation on each component and plugin and the options available for each. [Restated here and at the top of the answer because I only just added the link.]

Documentation for the point labels is in the plugin API documentation for : [PointLabels](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html) (plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js).

Specifically, the options to show the point labels are specified in

```
{
    seriesDefaults:{
      pointLabels: {show: true}
    }
}
```

To show the labels, but not those that are zero, you would use:

```
{
    seriesDefaults:{
      pointLabels: {
          show: true,
          hideZeros: true
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Makyen. Its working now. How do I make sure the numbers on the bar disappear ? I don't want the numbers to appear on the bars.

Comment: I updated this to indicate how to show the point labels and hide the zero values.  You can find the [API documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html) for the [PoinLabels plugin here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html)

Comment: Makyen - Need your help again. I have updated my question with an issue. I have to remove zeros , but when I add hideZero property, it removes the count for other colors and also changes the color

Comment: I am happy to help.  However, a couple of things would make it easier to do so.  A) The scope has shifted from the original question into a related, but separate question. Please split this question into a two questions (the original one about specifying colors and another about point labels. This will help people in the future who are searching for answers find what they are looking for.  When/if you do, feel free to add a comment here with a link so I am directly notified of the new question.

Comment: B) Please provide what you are using as a *complete* call to Jsplot. This will make it *much* easier for us to duplicate your issues and provide specific answers. Ideally, you could set up a JSFiddle with code showing the problem.  Here is a [JSFiddle with the basic Jqplot barchart includes configured](http://jsfiddle.net/hb0cy5u9/1/).  Feel free to Fork it and add your code/HTML/CSS. I understand that this can be a bit finicky, but it is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Makyen, I posted it as a new question. Can you please take a look ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385985/removing-zero-point-lables-on-stacked-bar-chat-in-jqplot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Within your jqplot you are missing seriesColors. Use it something like below:

```
$.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {
seriesColors:['#000000', '#ffffff', '#000000'],
seriesDefaults:{
renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
blah blah
```

Comment: Thanks Almas. Its working now. How do I make sure the numbers on the bar disappear ? I don't want the numbers to appear on the bars.

Comment: You need to switch off show to false for pointLabels which would be within seriesDefaults.

Comment: Thanks Almas again!! Yes, I can remove them now altogether. But now I need to just remove the zeros in case they appear on the bar. How do I do it ? Does JQPlot provides that facility ? If a particular color is not there, it shows a value as '0' . Can I get rid of them ?

Comment: @JohnsonTummalapalli These seems an addition to original requirement. Can you mark this question as resolved and open new question please.