# Removing zero value point lables on a Jqplot stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am having trouble removing the zeros (point lables) in a Jqplot stacked bar chart. I tried 'hideZero', but it's not working at all.

[image: Graph with zeros]

I tried different things; not sure what's wrong. I have imported the following packages:

```
jqplot.barRenderer.min.js
jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js
jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js
jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js
jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js
jqplot.pointLabels.min.js
jquery-2.0.3.js
jquery.jqplot.min.css
jquery.jqplot.min.js
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var s3 = [11, 28, 22, 47, 11, 11];
var s1 = [0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0];
var s2 = [1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0];
var dataArray = [s3, s1, s2];
var ticks = ['John', 'Tumm', 'Wen', 'Ken', 'Dolly'];

var options = {
    title: 'Title ',
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesColors: ["#eb4b3d", "#ffc800", "#009149"],
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true
        },
        rendererOptions: {
            barWidth: 25,
            varyBarColor: true,
        },
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            // renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            //  
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks,
        },
        yaxis: {
            //autoscale: true,
            //label: 'Application Count',
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: 5,
            max: 50
        }
    },
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: -30,
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    }
};

var plot = $.jqplot('chartDivId', dataArray, options);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chartDivId"/>
```

There is a [**JSFiddle of this problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhvdxwfh/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to look for documentation on how to do things is the [API Documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html). It has documentation on each component and plugin and the options available for each. [Restated here and at the top of the answer because I only just added the link.]

Documentation for the point labels is in the plugin API documentation for : [PointLabels](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html) (plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js).

You can remove the zero value labels by adding the property `hideZeros: true`. This means changing:

```
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
        },
```

to:

```
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            hideZeros: true
        },
```

There is a [**working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/arzv5j6o/1/).

[image]

The full JavaScript:

```
var s3 = [11, 28, 22, 47, 11, 11];
var s1 = [0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0];
var s2 = [1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0];
var dataArray = [s3, s1, s2];
var ticks = ['John', 'Tumm', 'Wen', 'Ken', 'Dolly'];

var options = {
    title: 'Title ',
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesColors: ["#eb4b3d", "#ffc800", "#009149"],
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            hideZeros: true
        },
        rendererOptions: {
            barWidth: 25,
            varyBarColor: true,
        },
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            // renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            //  
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks,
        },
        yaxis: {
            //autoscale: true,
            //label: 'Application Count',
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: 5,
            max: 50
        }
    },
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: -30,
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    }
};

var plot = $.jqplot('chartDivId', dataArray, options);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chartDivId"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working now. Initially hideZeros property didn't work because I had some other code that was overwriting the these properties.

Comment: This seems to work only with integers. It will hide treat 0.8 as a 0 and make it hidden.

Comment: @Paully Yep, it looks like`hideZeros` hides values between 0 and 1 (I didn't test for -1 to 0). Hmmm... it looks like it's a bug that's been reported: [JqPlot ignore values between -1 an 1](https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/issues/151), but nothing's happened on it for 4.5 years.

Answer (score 2):

I used this solution for to solve my problem with format hours

```
pointLabels: {
        show: true,
        formatString: '%s',
        formatter: function val(x, y) {

            //my Solution
            if (y != 0)

                return y.toString().toHHMMSS();
        },
    },
```